# how to index a JSF based website deployed on glassfish

Tags: jsf-2, seo, glassfish-3

Morning all,

I have an app deployed at www.mydomain.com/myAppp . I have created a virtual server and made myApp as the default web app.Hence anyone accessing www.myDomain.com gets redirected to www.myDomain.com/myApp. Now how do add a robots.txt file to my domain as google looks for www.domain.com/robots.txt.

The app is front ended by apache httpd.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks,
Goutham

Answer (score 1):

robots.txt should be under the ROOT directory for the application server. For tomcat its placed in 
    $CATALINA_HOME\webapps\ROOT

Not sure but putting in this folder will probably do "glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot"

or you can use Robots meta tag in your pages.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <h:head>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
</h:head>
<h:body></h:body>
```

Comment: hello many thanks for your answer. I have added meta tags to my web page, but still google looks for www.mydomain.com/robots.txt. Any suggestions or any pointers is most welcome. Thanks

Comment: "but still google looks for www.mydomain.com/robots.txt" -- means?

Comment: google crawler insists on having a robot.txt file at www.mydomain.com/rbots.txt not www.mydomain.com/myapp/robots.txt. I tried putting the file in the docroot folder , but for some reason it gives me 404 error... since i route my traffic through apache, its got to be something to do with it.. not sure how to go about achieving indexing..

Comment: If you are not able to use robots.txt, the meta tag would do the same work for you and robots.txt is not necessary anymore.

Comment: thanks ravi. I have updated the same , just waiting for new pages to be indexed now